# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using pip

Tags: python, pip

i think i messed up pip...i had python38-32,i realized that i have bit-32 so i went to control panel and deleted python38-32 and downloaded python38-64 but then i went to cmd to check whether pip is working or not by typing pip and i got the error :

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program
>   files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

and when i type where pip in cmd i get

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe
>   C:\Users\Muhammed Jaabir\python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe

then i manually went to program files to see whether i have this python38-32 file and it was there but idk what to do and i just want to use python38-64 pip pllzz help...

Comment: try uninstalling pip and reinstall

Comment: which pip i have pip.exe in python38-64 and python38-32 file

Comment: for the one you have error

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments? Something like Conda would help avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: i have conda too but after this error i tried typing conda in cmd and it says conda is not recognize as internal or external but conda works in anaconda prompt

Comment: thank you all for your answers it worked after i uninstalled python38-32